# HTML doesn't display when navigating to another view

Tags: html, angular, typescript, nativescript, angular5

I have an issue where i'm displaying a webview on one view and then once the user logs in i'm navigating to another view but the html for that view won't display, only the action bar. Help appreciated!

This is the login component navigating to secure--

```
this.router.navigate(["/secure"], { queryParams: { accessToken: accessToken } }).then((success)=>{

        console.log(success);
    });
}
```

This is the secure component-

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "ns-secure",
    templateUrl: "secure.component.html",
})

export class SecureComponent implements AfterViewInit{
    public accessToken: string;
    public onceLoggedInSrc: string; //TODO
    public htmlString: string;

    public constructor(private _router:Router, private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {         
        this.htmlString = '<span><h1>HtmlView demo in <font color="blue">NativeScript</font> App</h1></span>';
        this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.accessToken = params["accessToken"];
        console.log('accessToken2');
        console.log(this.accessToken);
        this.ngAfterViewInit();
        });

    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {  
        console.log('accessToken');   
    }
```

Comment: If you expect anyone to help you, you need to include the relevant code that you've already tried.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem [here are some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why are you calling Angular lifecycle callback (`ngAfterViewInit`) in the component's constructor !? Do you have binding to `htmlString` in your HTML (there is not HTML code posted)